# java generics - one impl class, multiple views

Tags: java

I have the interface defined as below and is implemented by a single class MatchedAddressImpl.

```
interface MatchedAddress extends HouseHelpData, StreetHelpData, TownHelpData

public class MatchedAddressDetails implements MatchedAddress
```

the client should be provided different views (HouseHelpData or StreetHelpData or TownHelpData or MatchedAddress) of the same MatchedAddressImpl. So I have provided the below API for the clients.

```
public List<MatchedAddress> matchedAddresses()
public List<? extends HouseHelpData> houseHelpData()
public List<? extends StreetHelpData> streetHelpData();
public List<TownHelpData> townHelpData();
```

the problem is that the client needs to do something like below and I read ineffective java that the return types should not contain wild cards as the client usage looks ugly...I appreciate it if someone can help me improve the API. what I want is to remove the wildcards from the above methods.

```
List<? extends StreetHelpData> streetHelpDataList = details.streetHelpData();
```

Comment: Have you thought about the benefits of not multiply implementing types. In general have one class do one thing, which isn't likely to happen if it has to be multiple things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most cases, the proper usage is simply `List<StreetHelpData>`. You would still be able to put objects of type `StreetHelpDataImpl`, for instance.

Wildcards are, in my opinion, misleading. Basically, for `List<? extends StreetHelpData>` it would mean: *"This list contains elements all of a certain type, which is a sub-type of StreetHelpData."*

**Wildcard example:**

Consider :

```
class Animal {}
class Lion extends Animal {}
class Tiger extends Animal {}
```

The list `List<? extends Animal>` contains either `Lions` only (`List<Lion>`), `Tigers` only (`List<Tiger>`), or both (`List<Animal>`). However, the list `List<Animal>` can contain all sorts of `Animals` - `Lions` and/or `Tigers` - at all times.

(Thanks to *Tom Hawtin* for his pointers)

Comment: `List<Animal>` is a `List<? extends Animal>`, so he latter can contain both `Lion`s and `Tiger`s at the same time (no idea how well they get on with each other).

Comment: You're right, thanks. And, no, I don't think they get along very well... :P

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need wildcards in your API to begin with? Get rid of them.

I'm guessing the reason you've done it that way is you've tried to do the following in your implementation:

```
public List<HouseHelpData> houseHelpData() {
    List<MatchedAddressDetails> results = new ArrayList<MatchedAddressDetails>();
    ... // populate it
    return results;
}
```

and you've got a compiler error. [Java Generic Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) explains why the above is illegal - basically it's to prevent you from inadvertedly adding `HouseHelpData` implementation incompatible with `MatchedAddressDetails` to the list and then trying to access it (from the downcasted list) as `MatchedAddressDetails` instance. What you **CAN** do, however, is:

```
public List<HouseHelpData> houseHelpData() {
    List<HouseHelpData> results = new ArrayList<HouseHelpData>();
    ...
    results.add(new MatchedAddressDetails());
    ...
    return results;
}
```

No wildcards necessary.

If that was not the reason for adding the wildcards to API, perhaps you can clarify your question and explain what was it.